# Criação da colunas em php conforme o comentario postgres

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, postgresql, tabela-banco-de-dados

Como melhorar a eficiência da função ao criar uma tabela no banco de dados com base em um array de colunas?

if(is_array($colunas['result'])) {

```
$sql .= 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS bitrix.empresas;';


foreach($colunas['result'] as $c => $f) {

        $campos_t[] = '"'.$campo.'" text';
        if(!empty($f['listLabel'])) $comment_c[] = 'COMMENT ON COLUMN bitrix.empresas."'.$c.'" IS \''.$f['listLabel'].'\';';
        elseif(!empty($f['title'])) $comment_c[] = 'COMMENT ON COLUMN bitrix.empresas."'.$c.'" IS \''.$f['title'].'\';';
    
    }
    
    $sql .= 'CREATE TABLE bitrix.empresas (';
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($campos_t); $i++) {
      $sql .= "\n".$campos_t[$i].' AS '.$comment_c[$i].',';
    }
    $sql = rtrim($sql, ',');
    $sql .= ') WITH ( OIDS=FALSE );';
    $sql .= implode("",$comment_c);
    $r = pg_query($linkGlobal, $sql);
    
    listarEmpresas();
```

}

Answer (score -3):

1. Use consultas mais bem preparadas ao invés
   de juntar diretamente os valores das colunas no SQL. Isso ajuda a
   evitar ataques de hackers que tentam injetar código malicioso em seu
   banco de dados. Também pode melhorar a eficiência da execução.
2. Usar transações. É como um pacote que coloca todas as operações
   necessárias no banco de dados. Isso garante que todas as operações
   sejam concluídas com êxito antes que a transação seja confirmada.
   Dessa forma, se algo der errado, não afetará outras operações.
3. Em vez de criar uma lista de campos e comentários
   em um loop, recomendo o uso de funções nativas do PHP, como
   array_map e array_reduce. Isso permite que você crie essas listas
   mais rapidamente.
4. É recomendável usar arrays para armazenar comentários em vez de
   armazenar comentários lado a lado. Então você pode usar a função
   implodir para concatená-los antes de executar a consulta.
5. Em vez de verificar duas vezes se
   listLabel ou title está vazio, é melhor verificar apenas uma vez e
   armazenar o resultado em uma variável que pode ser usada
   posteriormente assim evitando redundância no código.

**Exemplo de como a função pode ser melhorada:**

```
    if(is_array($colunas['result'])) {
  $sql = 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS bitrix.empresas;';
  pg_query($linkGlobal, $sql);

  $campos_t = array_map(
    function ($campo) {
      return '"' . $campo . '" text';
    },
    array_keys($colunas['result'])
  );

  $comentarios = array_reduce(
    array_values($colunas['result']),
    function ($acc, $coluna) {
      $label = !empty($coluna['listLabel']) ? $coluna['listLabel'] : $coluna['title'];
      $acc[] = 'COMMENT ON COLUMN bitrix.empresas."' . $coluna['ID'] . '" IS \'' . $label . '\';';
      return $acc;
    },
    []
  );

  $sql = 'CREATE TABLE bitrix.empresas (' . implode(', ', $campos_t) . ') WITH ( OIDS=FALSE );';
  pg_query($linkGlobal, $sql);

  $sql = implode('', $comentarios);
  pg_query($linkGlobal, $sql);

  listarEmpresas();
}
```

Caso não resolva seu problema me comunique que vou tentar ajuda-lo.

Comment: [Conteúdo gerado por ChatGPT não é permitido na rede](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8842/conte%c3%bado-gerado-por-chatgpt-n%c3%a3o-%c3%a9-permitido-na-rede)